# Django: complex order by query with nested models

Tags: django, foreign-keys, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I have following 3 models

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.utils import timezone


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
    blank=False,
    max_length=256
    )


class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
    blank=False,
    max_length=256
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(
    Product,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=False,
    blank=True
    )


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
    blank=False,
    max_length=256
    )

    task_group = models.ForeignKey(
    TaskGroup,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=False,
    blank=True
    )
    
    execute_at = models.DateField(
    blank=True
    null=True,
    )
```

I can order the products by Task `execute_at` date.

```
Products.objects.annotate(
    last_task=Max('taskgroup__task__execute_at')
).order_by('-last_task')
```

However, I need to consider only the first date that is greater than today i.e I need something like

```
Products.objects.annotate(
    last_task=('taskgroup__task__execute_at' >= timezone.now()).first()
).order_by('last_task')
```

So I need to order products by the closest Task execute_at date i.e closest to current date.

How can I do this? It would be nice to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **DJANGO 2.0** we can use the [**filter argument**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) to achieve this.

The below line must be do what you want:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Q

Products.objects.annotate(
    last_task=Min(
        'taskgroup__task__execute_at',
        filter=Q(taskgroup__task__execute_at__gte=timezone.now()
))).order_by('last_task')
```

Comment: I do not need to filter products, I need to order products by task execute_at date where `execute_at date is >= timezone.now()`

Comment: @StaticName,  to do that first you have to do filter `execute_at__gte=timezone.now()`. Then you can do `order_by("taskgroup__task__execute_at")` for ascending  or `order_by("taskgroup__task__execute_at")` for descending.

Comment: @zelenyjan, i think that he need first item, from the question: _I need to consider only the first date that is greater than today_

Comment: @StaticName, if you don't need to filter simple exclude it and use only `....order_by("-taskgroup__task__execute_at").first()`. But to get items greater or equal to **timezone.now()** you have to do `filter()`.

Comment: Even you do the filter, it does not work. Because at the end products are ordered by `taskgroup__task__execute_at`, so filter has no effect in this query.

Comment: @StaticName, have you tried to execute the code from my answer? What response do you get? If you do the filtering, you can get only products greater or equal to **timezone.now()**. See [**Making queries**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: @NKSM I believe that perhaps OP wants to order by the first `taskgroup__task__execute_at` and not get the first `Product`. Your answer appears to be very close perhaps `.filter(...).annotate(min_execute_at=Min('taskgroup__task__execute_at')).order_by('min_execute_at')` might do the trick

Comment: @StaticName, I have not been able to understand your question immediately. I edited my answer with the correct approach.